# Django - How to model this correctly?

Tags: python, django, model

I want to model the following situation. I have a table of items, and a table of players, and a player can have many items and have multiple copies of the same item. I can easily model the player having multiple items:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)

class Player(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Term)
```

But I want to know the number of each item the player has i.e. each items frequency. How can  I best model this in Django. (I've simplfied my actual models/problem to get my point accross :) )

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items are non-unique you can use a PlayerItem model and define it as a [through model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) as Daniel Roseman suggested. To avoid saving the same item twice you can use `unique_together`:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)

class Player(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='PlayerItem')

class PlayerItem(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('player', 'item')
```

However if the items will vary slightly or you need to store acquisition date for instance, you need a different setup:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = False)

class Player(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='PlayerItem')

class PlayerItem(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    acquired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

This time you will be saving duplicates of (player, item) tuple, one for each item. And then you can get the number of a specific item via `count()`.

I would also like to note that you can't reach `PlayerItem` model from neither `Item` nor `Player`. In both cases you need to query `PlayerItem` directly to access the extra fields. (as documented)

Answer (score 5):

Use an [explicit `through` table](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) with a `quantity` field.